# Dynamically node generation function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

```
var v = [
    {
        "message": {
            "code": "S200",
            "message": "Success"
        },
        "data": {
            "car": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "val": "Toyota"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "val": "Honda"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "val": "Nissan"
                }
            ],
            "truck": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "val": "Benz"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "val": "Volvo"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I have a dynamic json shown like above.
how could get v[0].data.car node dynamically(without using v[0], v[1] etc) in undescorejs or angularjs. Is Hashmap is possible?.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the array in angularjs, like this

```
v.forEach(function(element){
  console.log(element.data.car[0]);//Over here you can again iterate the car array, I have used the first element instead
});
```

Comment: we are trying to avoid loops. thats why we are looking for hashmap solutions.

Comment: @Kris please update the question explaining what exactly you're expecting from a *hashmap* solution.

Comment: @Kris: You would then need to convert the array into objects having different keys